# Bipartite graph non-isomorphic to a subgraph of any k-cube

Tags: graph-theory

Find a bipartite graph that is not isomorphic to a subgraph of any k-cube

Comment: In addition, showing what you already know (or think) about the problem will allow the community to help you more effectively.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker and I don't quite understand the question. So the question wants us to find a special bipartite graph that is not isomorphic to any subgraph of any k-cube? Or to find a kind of subgraph of any k-cube, then find a bipartite that is not isomorphic to the above subgraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Note that the $k$-cube can be represented with nodes the $k$ length strings of $0$s and $1$s, where two nodes are adjacent if they differ in exactly one point.  Consider the points $(1,0, \dots ,0)$, and $(0,1, 0, \dots ,0)$. How many points in any $k$-cube are adjacent to both of those points?